# Use build in validation to validate dynamic created View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

I want to make a task system where the content data is able to expand dynamically (With different kinds of inputs (Text, Images, Dropdowns etc.). My plan is to create the following model, and with the help from some custom HtmlHelpers generate my view.

**Model:**

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TaskData> TaskData { get; set; }
}

public enum TaskDataType
{
    TextType1, TextType2, E-mail, Image
}

public class TaskData
{
    public int TaskDataId { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public TaskDataType Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

Validation for the Task, works out of the box with the default HtmlHelpers, but when i try to make something like:

```
    @if (Model.TaskData != null)
    {
        foreach (var taskData in Model.TaskData)
        {
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(td => taskData.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(td => taskData.Data)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(td => taskData.Data)
        }
    }
```

In my View, the validation starts to go wrong, client site validation only validates the first input in the forech loop, and the ModelState in the controller does not contain any data regarding the TaskData fields.

**So I have 2 quetions:**

1. Is this the right path, or do I need to think of this in a different way?
2. If this is valid method of making what i want, is there a way to make the build in validation work?

Comment: I found out why the validation didn't work, the name and id is the same on every entry. Sorry for that. But it would still be nice if someone could give me a hint, if i'am heading in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use for loop in order to post field values as well as get the in build validation work for you.

```
@if (Model.TaskData != null)
    {
        for(int i=0; i< Model.TaskData.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.TaskData[i].Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TaskData[i].Data)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskData[i].Data)
        }
    }
```